# PHP: Using PDO object and multiple prepare statement affects the Statement object returned

Tags: php, pdo

For the sake of avoiding unnecessary information, roughly my code flows as follows:

```
$db = new PDO(DSN, DB_USER, DB_PW);


$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM Table1";

// fetching the first result
$stt1 = $db->prepare($sql1);
if ($stt1->execute()) {
    $result = $stt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

// doing update in the middle by using the SAME $db object, but different statement variable
$sql2 = "UPDATE Table1 SET field1 = 'footest1' WHERE id = 1";
$stt2 = $db->prepare($sql2);
$stt2->execute();

// fetching the next result
$result = $stt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Ok, I ran this, and to my surprise, when I am fetching my next result, I get false. Does preparing another statement ($stt2) in the middle interrupt my already created $stt1?

And I have 15+ records on that table.

Update: It seems like the execute method of the statement object is the reason my second fetch is returning false. For this to work, calling $stt1->execute() again before fetching the second time solves this problem... But this shows that there is some connection via the execute method between all the statement object?

Comment: I can't find a doc reference for this, but it seems that you can't reuse a prepared statement this way.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Exactly what is confusing me. Even though I stored the first statement and the second one on two different variable which also mean different place in memory....

Comment: I think it might have worked had you not actually used the first statement.

Comment: It may depend on whether you use buffered or non-buffered queries. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php

Comment: instead of fetch use fetchAll then then you wont need to continue grabbing results from the first

Comment: If something returns false, I would assume there is some error - do you have error reporting turned on to show the errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different databases have different constraints. This is not an issue with PHP or PDO, but with the database connection.

While you can rely on any DB connector to support at least one cursor with pending rows, many databases will limit you at one, and require you to either fully fetch or explicitly close the underlying cursor before executing a new statement.

This is indeed a property of the database connection, as all PDO statements are bound to one. (Where would they fetch the data from if they didn't remain bound to the database connection?) If you're using a database that only supports one open prepared statement at a time, you'll have no choice but to either serialize your accesses or open multiple connections to the database. You might also want to take a look at [the `closeCursor` method of the `PDOStatement` class](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php).